# SubSite creation under SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, teamsite

I have one confusion related to SharePoint SubSite.

Currently, I am creating SubSites under Communication Site Collection and Team Site Collections.

Will the Subsite feature be deprecated soon by Microsoft?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Sub site is a legacy architecture and it's a concept not recommended for years. It's still possible to create sub sites (but also to block their creation). Microsoft advises to consider hub instead (only for SharePoint in Microsoft 365):

> Instead of using subsites, we recommend that you use hub sites. SharePoint hub sites allow you to group similar topics and content together using modern architecture design. Plan to create hub sites.

Source: [Manage site creation in SharePoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/manage-site-creation)

Documentation: [What is a SharePoint hub site?](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/what-is-a-sharepoint-hub-site-fe26ae84-14b7-45b6-a6d1-948b3966427f)

Comment: With the SharePoint HUb site can we create a child site/sub-site under the site? Thanks

Comment: Yes you can, but still, create subsites, even within a hub, is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

After my internal and external searches, there is currently no documentation stating that the Subsite feature be deprecated soon by Microsoft.By the way，Community sites can't be subsites.